# What are the best ways to get rid of unimportant input neurons?

Tags: optimization, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I have a well trained neural network consisting of about 40 input neurons and letting me classify some items by patterns. Each neuron receives some separate input parameter value. I'm pretty sure that not all input parameters are important in achieving end result, so that if I exclude them my network should produce almost the same result. What is the most effective and fast way to get rid of unnecessary input neurons in the network, preferably not to retrain whole network? Thank you

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=neural+net+pruning

Comment: What characteristics of those neurons makes you think they are not needed?

Comment: Oh, it's called 'Pruning'. Thanks for the hint, I'm new in NN. What makes me feel some of them are not needed? Initially I took every characteristic of item and add it to a collection of input parameters to classify them, common sense says me only few of this 40 characteristics actually do affect end result.

Comment: Potentially, you could encode those "common sense" rules.

Comment: Do you mean it might happen all this 40 inputs are crucial in achieving results? In the case I'll see 'pruning' does not work well, right? I'll see results are not so good. Anyway it's worth to try coz I need to improve my network performance

Comment: It is possible, that while your data might only have few parameters, those parameters will not be well aligned with your inputs. If you want to reduce the size of your input you should instead do PCA or factor analysis on the data before feeding it to neural network. Though that would definitely require you to retrain the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two answers to do that easily and quickly :

- You can, if you have to train your NN (you'll have to re-train it anyway if you prune it), cut connections with a weight under a fixed threshold and, then, remove neuron without connections;
- You can compute the Shapley value for each subset of input neurons and prune those which have "bad" value : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapley_value

Answer (score 1):

from real Test Data produce 40 different test set

Each set only one input values randomize

Test these data sets with "well Trained NN"

Compare the results